# Using sqlalchemy models in django admin

Tags: django, orm, sqlalchemy, django-admin

I am using SQLAlchemy ORM for my models in Django. I would like to register the SQLAlchemy's models in Django's admin.site. Is there any way to achieve so. It seems like Django's admin.site allows only Django's model to register.

Comment: You can register your model in django admin site by ```admin.site.register(YourModel)``` . Did you read this django documentaion ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects.

Comment: I mean SQLAlchemy's model, not Django model.

Comment: have you tried it? I usually use Flask with SQLAlchemy, and there is a [flask-admin](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for the representation

Comment: Currently we are using Django framework and some of the tables needs complex sql operations. So we are going to use SQLAlchemy ORM models for those tables. But we still like to utilize the Django's admin.site feature for those models if it is possible.